# Isn't this question way too broad?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I came upon the following review audit today: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/10218382

After analyzing the question I opted to vote to close the question for being too broad. As it stands, I find the question very vague and lacking details. The problem described "I'm getting an URL not found error" could be caused by numerous reasons and IMHO the following things are wrong with this question:

- The OP does not provide a clear description of what steps were taken to get to this error
- The problem might be local, for example (but none of those details have been specified by the OP):

  - OP might have DNS resolution problems
  - OP might not have set any possible Proxy settings properly
  - A local (or corporate) firewall may be blocking access to the requested resource
- The problem is very likely to be a temporary problem with the repository/site where the tool he's trying to download has to come from

All things considered, the question contains very little details and is a "Is anyone else having this problem as well?" question at best. In my opinion this is not a suitable question for the Q&A format. Because what would that look like?

> **Q:** I am getting a 404 error, how to fix it?
>   **A:** Contact the maintainer and ask them to fix the link.

I don't see how this is a good fit for SO, but apparently I am wrong. So I am very curious what the arguments might be to keep questions like this open. because I like to learn from my mistakes. And I just don't see what my mistake was here.

Comment: I don't think you made any mistake. I also consider that question too broad. It's just a bad audit.

Comment: WTF??  We get SO questions for bad links, now?

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, apparently. And I also assume that people have started abusing the upvote button for saying "Yes, I get the same error!".

Comment: It's a very poor question, you can see that from the only answer its received which is at best a comment. I've downvoted it and cast a close vote on it so hopefully it won't be appearing as an audit again.

Comment: It has 5 upvotes, so it must be good *facepalm*

Comment: @Thomas It actually had 9 up votes in total. It's (currently) down to a score of 2. Now 1...

Comment: @DavidG: at least the Meta effect still works. That's fine.

Comment: Well, all he has to do is pick up his phone, call Google and ask for tech support.  Oh, wait.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is way too broad and as you can see now it currently has a score of **-1** (9 upvotes and 10 downvotes). It is also closed as **Too Broad**. Meta agrees with you and has taken care of this question appropriately.

It was a very unfortunate review audit. Your review was correct but unfortunate that it happened to be an audit. The best thing you can do is move on and continue to review questions appropriately.

Comment: Yes, thanks everyone for thinking along and posting your thoughts. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything obvious, since I failed the audit. But it seems like I didn't miss anything after all.